# Installing local packages with Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, pymysql

I am using Anaconda with 64 bit Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 machine that is necessarily isolated from the internet.  I am having difficulty installing local packages.  Right now I am stuck on PyMySQL, but I imagine I would also have the same problem with other packages.  My system PATH variable has Anaconda at the beginning.

Trying a path to the unpacked folder:

```
conda install –-offline c:\temp\PyMySQL-master\pymysql
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - c:\temp\pymysql-master\pymysql
```

What does this error mean?  I have tried using a tar file and I get the same error message.  This is the same message I get if I spell the filename wrong, so there is something I am missing to get it to recognize the file. Do I need to create a channel for a local package?  How would I do that?  Is there anything else I should try?

Here is the response in verbose mode:

```
conda install --offline --verbose c:\temp\pymysql.tar
Fetching package metadata ...........
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.21
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.21
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.13.final.0
       requests version : 2.14.2
       root environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2  (writable)
    default environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs
                          C:\Users\lab1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\cygwin\home\lab1\.conda\envs
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs
                          C:\Users\lab1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch  (offline)
            config file : C:\cygwin\home\lab1\.condarc
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : True
             user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.14.2 CPython/2.7.13 Windows/7 Windows/6.1.7601
          administrator : True

`$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py install --offline --verbose c:\temp\pymysql.tar`

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 632, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 137, in _main
        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 80, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 306, in install
        raise PackageNotFoundError(error_message)
    PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
      - c:\temp\pymysql.tar
```

Comment: Have you tried the --use-local flag?

Comment: Yes, and the error message is the same.  In fact, I get the same message if I spell the name wrong.

Comment: You can install PyMySQL from the default anaconda channel: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pymysql . I'm not sure that conda installing a .tar file will work.

Comment: But anaconda.org requires an internet connection.

Comment: Would it be possible to download the tar.bz2 file from anaconda and move it over to your isolated machine? You could probably conda install from that file

Comment: I could try, but that is basically like what I tried already, and the error message seems to say it doesn't see my file.  There must be a step or option that I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

Every conda package ever built to date has a .tar.bz2 extension, and this assumption is baked in deeply.  Someday we'll probably add different package types, compression algorithms, and extensions, but that's a ways off.  So to work, your command needs to be

```
conda install --offline --verbose c:\temp\pymysql.tar.bz2
```

and `pymysql.tar.bz2` needs to be a real conda package. (i.e. if you unpack that tarball and there's no `info/files` file in it, then it's not a conda package)